App not authorized Firebase Flutter android
I have a Flutter Android app that uses Firebase Authentication. It was working fine with the old Firebase project. After switching to a new laptop machine to run project on different device I get the following error when trying to send OTP even after adding the SHA-1 and SHA-256 key on firebase for that device:

This app is not authorized to use Firebase Authentication. Please verify that the correct package name and SHA-1 are configured in the Firebase Console. [App validation failed]

Here's what I've done so far:
Added the package name and SHA-1, SHA-256 keys to the Firebase Console.
Enabled Phone Authentication in Sign-In methods.
Enabled Play Integrity API.
Downloaded the new google-services.json and placed it in the android/app directory.
Verified the package name and SHA keys multiple times.
Additional Info:
My app is not on the Play Store. I'm testing it directly from Android Studio.
Created a brand new app and implemented Firebase Auth, but still facing the same issue.
Steps I've Tried:
Verified the package name and SHA keys multiple times.
Ensured the correct placement of google-services.json.
Updated Firebase dependencies.
Cleaned and rebuilt the project.
Checked Logcat for errors.
What else could I be missing? Any help is appreciated.

I've been experiencing the same issue for the past three days. I've verified the package name, SHA-1, and SHA-256 keys, and even created a new Firebase project and a new Flutter project, but the issue persists. Interestingly, everything works fine on iOS, but I'm facing problems only on Android. Have you found a solution?

Try to add new hash in https://console.cloud.google.com/ manually:

Open https://console.cloud.google.com/
Go to API's & Services
Selecte "Credentials" in the right part of the screen
Tap "+ CREATE CREDENTIALS" -> OAuth client ID
Select "Android", input name (just for you, doesn't metter), package name (com.smth.smth - this one from your app) and new sha-1 hash

After download google-services.json again from firebase and try.
If this wouldn't work or your sha already in google console, you can try to reconfigurate firebase in app via FlutterFire CLI - https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android
